# FileOpenPicker throws access denied exception when starting it from a tile rather than a button in Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, fileopenpicker

I'm trying to use the FileOpenPicker API by starting it from a pinned tile in Windows Phone 8.1.

The tile has a command stored in it for which the application would start the FileOpenPicker when launched from that tile. In this case the FileOpenPicker API throws an E_ACCESSDENIED exception. When calling the same code from a button in the application it doesn't crash. So, the capabilities set to the application are ok, it just seems that the environment the FileOpenPicker is called isn't the same.

```cs
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker(); 
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail; 
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary; 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg"); 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg"); 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png"); 

openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

The last line is what crashes when starting from tile. Both scenarios call this inside the MainPage, after it's constructed.
The tile calls it like this, from App.xaml.cs/OnLaunched():

```cs
if (!e.TileId.Equals("App"))
{
    var mainPage = rootFrame.Content as Views.MainPage;
    if (mainPage != null)
    {
        string command = e.Arguments;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command) && command.Equals(Utils.TileCommand))
        {
              mainPage.TakePicture ();
        }
    }
    //else
    //{
    //    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage), e.Arguments);
    //}
}
```

I also tried the else part (commented out) and calling the TakePicture() method in MainPage.NavigatedTo () instead, but the same happens.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not versed into Windows Phone 8.1 apps but your FileOpenPicker should run asynchronously of the UI thread.

Have you tried to use the async method as following ?

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker(); 
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail; 
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary; 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg"); 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg"); 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png"); 

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, SebD, but Studio says: "warning CS0618: 'FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync()' is obsolete: 'PickSingleFileAsync will be unavailable for Windows Phone 8.1. Instead, use PickSingleFileAndContinue'".

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be that rootFrame is null or its contents are null.. Check if rootFrame is null or content is null in OnLaunched method. It could be issue.

Comment: Rohit, there is no problem with the rootFrame, the exception is thrown on line openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();. Thanks for the input.